# Server routing config Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one question about ng2 release routing. 
When I used old routing where we can keep all routing config in one file I created pre-config system where I loaded route config from server and after that I started my application.

But now in new router I shuould create own routes for root and feature modules (NgModule) and import it to that NgModule.

Is it possible to create one route config for parent and child modules and pass it to application from start? Because I don't know how I can do it in current routing system. Thanks.